# Type Error: 'expected class "execute" to be a function not a method' When Removing Poll

Tags: python, scripting, error

i'm following a 2.79 blender python tutorial for beginners, under 2.83.2.  i'm having trouble removing the poll from the classmethod.  (is there a reason i shouldn't do that?)  this works:

```
class MonkeyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.make_monkey"
    bl_label = "Monkey Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MonkeyOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MonkeyOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

...

but if i comment out or delete the poll lines, it throws this error:

> line 61, in register
> TypeError: expected Operator, MonkeyOperator class "execute" attribute to be a function, not a method

the execute is exactly the same as before. so... ???

Comment: I can not reproduce your error (btw: line 61 is not part of the code posted). In general I'd suggest to check/poll for *Object Mode* (if your goal is to add an object) or at least `return True` in case you need `poll()` method later on.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to remove or [comment out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696966) the method including the [`@classmethod` decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```
import bpy

class MonkeyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.make_monkey"
    bl_label = "Monkey Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # do stuff
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MonkeyOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MonkeyOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

For [multiline comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696966) you can use triple-quoted strings:

```
'''
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.object is None
'''
```